# zero mq and python : not sending without sleep command

Tags: python, zeromq, sleep

If I send a command without a sleep in the loop, zeromq will not send the data.  However, if a really really short duration sleep in the loop, for example     time.sleep(0.1), it sends the data fine. Why?

This version of the code works :

zero_mq_pub.py

```
import signal
import time
import zmq
import random

signal.signal(signal.SIGINT, signal.SIG_DFL)

context = zmq.Context()
socket = context.socket(zmq.PUB)
socket.bind('tcp://*:5555')
float_no = str(random.uniform(20,60)).encode()

for i in range(100):
    float_no = str(random.uniform(20,60)).encode()
    socket.send(float_no)
    time.sleep(0.1)
```

zero_mq_pub.py (doesnt work )

```
import signal
import time
import zmq
import random

signal.signal(signal.SIGINT, signal.SIG_DFL)

context = zmq.Context()
socket = context.socket(zmq.PUB)
socket.bind('tcp://*:5555')
float_no = str(random.uniform(20,60)).encode()

for i in range(100):
    float_no = str(random.uniform(20,60)).encode()
    socket.send(float_no)
```

zero_mq_receiver

```
import signal
import zmq


signal.signal(signal.SIGINT, signal.SIG_DFL)

context = zmq.Context()

socket = context.socket(zmq.SUB)
socket.connect('tcp://localhost:5555')
socket.setsockopt(zmq.SUBSCRIBE, b'')

while True:
    message = socket.recv_string()
    float_message = float(message)
    print("type is: ", type(float_message), "    the message is ", float_message )
```

Comment: You should know that `0.1` is exactly the same as `000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000.1`.

Answer (score 0):

I found out that pyzmq official example sleeping 0.1 seconds as well

source: https://github.com/zeromq/pyzmq/blob/main/examples/pubsub/topics_pub.py#L61

This example (topics_pub and topics_sub in the same repository folder) works with some changes strings to bytes.